# Merging two XML docs and overwriting XML fields when found

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm stumped at merging two XML documents together, I want the new second xml I'm merging with to overwrite the existing fields when found, and created when not;

```
<filemeta filetype="Video">
    <heading>News Headlines</heading>
    <shortblurb>The latest news roundup</shortblurb>
    <description />
    <files>
        <file type="coverimage">headlines.png</file>
    </files>
    <Comments />
    <AlbumTitle />
    <TrackNumber />
    <ArtistName />
    <Year />
    <Genre />
    <TrackTitle />
    <duration>00:02:22</duration>
    <totalbitrate>1168 kb/s</totalbitrate>
    <videocodec>h264</videocodec>
    <pixelformat>yuv420p</pixelformat>
    <resolution>640x360</resolution>
    <audiocodec>aac</audiocodec>
    <audiofrequency>44100 Hz</audiofrequency>
    <channelmulplicity>stereo</channelmulplicity>
    <audioformat>s16</audioformat>
    <audiobitrate>111 kb/s</audiobitrate>
</filemeta>
```

and merge with this one;

```
<filemeta type="Video">
    <duration>00:00:45</duration>
    <totalbitrate>548 kb/s</totalbitrate>
    <videocodec>h264</videocodec>
    <pixelformat>yuv420p</pixelformat>
    <resolution>720x576</resolution>
    <audiocodec>aac</audiocodec>
    <audiofrequency>48000 Hz</audiofrequency>
    <channelmulplicity>stereo</channelmulplicity>
    <audioformat>s16</audioformat>
    <audiobitrate>65 kb/s</audiobitrate>
</filemeta>
```

I've tried working with various [XSLT scripts](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#merge) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/11/20/38885.aspx) however they only seem to append the second script to the end of the first one, thus invalidating my XML.  Ideally I'd like todo this C#

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible (**brute**) XSLT 1.0 solution, just to give an idea.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="data2" select="document('test_i2.xml')/filemeta"/>

    <xsl:template match="filemeta">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="element1" select="name(.)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count($data2/*[name()=$element1])!=0">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$data2/*[name()=$element1]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467798/how-to-merge-2-xml-files-with-c), I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried the top code however I get a ArgumentNullException error - 'column' argument cannot be null.